# in bootstrap, How to force height of a div as height img-responsive class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div that looks like this:

```
<div class="main-div col-xs-12 col-md-6">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <a href="">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/285x251">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="content col-xs-6">  
    <h4>Header</h4>
    <p>Paragraph test</p>

    <div class="buttons">
      <div class="btn btn-primary col-md-6">Add to cart</div>
      <div class="btn btn-success col-md-6">View Item</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and I want that `img-responsive` class will determine the total height of the main div

So if it's will look like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/y9Let9dh/

so I want that `max-height` of  a `main-div` class, will be as img-responsive height

and `<p>` of `div class="content "` will be `overflow: hidden` style

My problem that I have no idea how I get the height of `img-responsive` at any given time

My goal is also, to do
The buttons always in the bottom, parallel to the img

Comment: .buttons{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:30px;
}

value of bottom shall be equal to the height of the button to fit them in view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Narek_T/y9Let9dh/1/). Are you looking way like this?
You need to set `overflow: hidden` to your `main-div`, wrap your content into some div (I called it `cont-inner`) and set `position: absolute` to him, because absolute positioned elements has not change parents height.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer!
But how do I make the buttons appear always,
And always will be bottom regardless of the amount of a text?